# Replacement for specific org.apache.axis classes

Tags: java, apache-axis

A legacy java project was given to our team to update it, so i was given the task. The project uses many org.apache.axis classes, so i'm trying the replacement, [apache axis2](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/index.html). But i cannot seem to find an axis2 replacement for some of the old axis classes. The classes are the following:

```
org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext
org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer
org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer

org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.CalendarSerializer
org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer
org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.EnumSerializer
org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.EnumDeserializer

org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc
org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc
```

I looked at the [migration guide](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/migration.html) for something like a list of old axis clases and their axis2 equivalent, with no luck.

I also searched the axis2 [api docs](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/index.html) and the [package tree](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/overview-tree.html) for the classes without any result. Finally i went trough the [deprecated list](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/deprecated-list.html) but again the classes were not listed.

So my question is if there are any apache axis2 replacements for the classes listed, or they no longer exist?